# Floating point ARM support in WEC7

Tags: floating-point, arm, armv7, windows-embedded-compact, platform-builder

In VS2008 Platform Builder, the selection options for "Target architecture for compiler" of "ARMv7 with VFPv3-D32" will use these build options: `/QRarch7 /QRfpe- /arch:VFPv3-D32`

[uSoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg154857(v=winembedded.70).aspx) say's:
For platforms **without** VFP hardware, use the flag ENABLE_HARDWARE_FLOAT=0 or /QRfpe- so the compiler will generate code that handles floating-point operations using integer arithmetic.

So when you tell the compiler that the VFP HW is present, you add a build option to use integer math rather than use the VFP hardware.

This doesn't make sense.  Can someone explain this?

EDIT:
Its worth noting that the VFP is optional on some ARMv7 chips but there is no ARMv7 nonVFP option in PlatformBuilder.

Another [uSoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552256.aspx) post that says /QRfpe- enables the VFP HW support.  (This post dates back to VS2005.)